# How to pass Git SSH credentials to Gradle release plugin in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, gradle, gradle-release-plugin

I’m trying to employ the Gradle [release plugin](https://github.com/researchgate/gradle-release) on our client’s Jenkins (1.x, so no Jenkinsfile pipelines… ). I tested it on my box, and everything is well. However, when I invoke the build job, it fails with this output:

```
Task :foundation:checkUpdateNeeded FAILED
Running [git, remote, update] produced an error: [Permission denied (publickey).
```

I know that Jenkins has got a set of Git SSH Credentials, because the job starts by checking out a fresh copy from Git using these.

How can we make the release plugin use the credentials which are configured for the job during checkout?

Comment: did you ever get this sorted out?

Comment: I'm afraid not. The client has since upgraded Jenkins to a scriptable version which rendered this issue unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

Gradle release does not allow to configure the git credentials. Even this question is unnecesary I will put two different possibilities to sort this out because I was struggling all the day with this. Why? Because I am not allowed to use SSH anymore in the company and we are moving to docker containers to distribute our CI pipelines:

1.) Put the SSH key under user jenkins ~/.ssh/id_rsa as it is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49261053/ssh-git-access-using-gradle-release-plugin)

2.) Use "Execute shell" before the gradle release to configure the remote:

[image]

Token must be configured as [an environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10625259/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-jenkins). This to answer the initial question.

3.) More advance functionalities can be included with the use of pipelines. I put below the Jenkinsfile to execute gradle release (you can use also `sshagent (credentials: ['credential'])` and then you do not need the git stuff):

```
    // GITLAB_API_TOKEN
    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'nexususer', variable: 'nexusUsername'),
        string(credentialsId: 'nexuspassword', variable: 'nexusPassword'),
        string(credentialsId: 'nexussnapshoturl', variable: 'nexusSnapshotUrl'),
        string(credentialsId: 'nexusreleaseurl', variable: 'nexusReleaseUrl'),
        string(credentialsId: 'token', variable: 'GITLAB_API_TOKEN')]) {
        if (env.BRANCH_NAME == "master") {
            stage('Release') {
                gitlabCommitStatus(name: 'Release') {
                    // Run the gradle release
                    sh 'git config user.email "email"'
                    sh 'git config user.name "name"'
                    sh "git remote rm origin"
                    sh "git remote add origin https://username:${GITLAB_API_TOKEN}@yourrepo"
                    sh "gradle clean release -Prelease.useAutomaticVersion=true"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a freestyle job and you're using private key to authenticate:

1. Check option `Use secret text(s) or file(s)`. Select git credentials and enter names for environment variables that you need to import.
2. In Gradle build part import your key environment variable (and others if needed) as a project property: -Pkeylocation=$KEY_VARIABLE_NAME

Answer (score 0):

Use the below script in the Shell command before executing the Gradle task that runs the git command to update the repo.

Here GITHUB_SSH_KEY is an environment variable injected from credentials using the "SSH User Private Key" option.

```
cat "${GITHUB_SSH_KEY}" > ./build/sshkey
cd build
chmod 600 sshkey    
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add sshkey
cd ..

git config core.sshCommand "ssh -i ./build/sshkey -o 'IdentitiesOnly yes'"
git config --global user.email "commiter@jenkins.com"
git config --global user.name "flastname"
```

Note: If the build folder doesn't exist, insert "mkdir build" on top of the script.